# PHPWord: Text inside table cell isn't fitting in one line

Tags: php, phpword

My code:

```
<?php
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setCompatibility(false);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setZipClass(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PCLZIP);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);

    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(14);
    $header = $section->addHeader();
    $tableStyle = array(
        'width'            => 100 * 50,
        'unit'             => 'pct',
        'borderColor' => '000000',
        'borderSize' => 2,
        'bgColor' => '008000',
        'alignment'=> \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER,
        'layout'=> \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::LAYOUT_FIXED,
        `fitText`=>TRUE
    );
    $phpWord->addTableStyle('myTable', $tableStyle);
    $table = $header->addTable('myTable');
    $table->addRow(2800, array("exactHeight" => true, 'cantSplit' => false));
    $cell = $table->addCell()->addImage("../image1.jpg",array(
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 150,
    ));
    $cell1 = $table->addCell()->addImage("../image2.jpg",array(
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 150,
    ));
    $cell2 = $table->addCell()->addImage("../image3.jpg",array(
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 150,
    ));
    $cell3 = $table->addCell()->addText("\n\n22 Mar, 2023 (News clips)", 
    array('bold'=>true,'color'=>'FFFFFF','bgColor'=>'A52A2A','size'=>12));

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('news.docx');
?>
```

The output that I get is:

[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiQqS.png)

Everything is fine, but why is the text in the last column wrapped? I tried increasing the `cell width`, to make the text fit in one single line:

```
$cell3 = $table->addCell(50000)->addText("\n\n22 Mar, 2023 (News clips)", 
array('bold'=>true,'color'=>'FFFFFF','bgColor'=>'A52A2A','size'=>12));
```

But the output is still the same. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see a width defined for the cell3, have you tried setting one, same values than the others?

Comment: Yes I have tried setting the width to `50000 twips` but the result is still the same.